# Revit API, Prevent document opening

Tags: revit-api

I would like to prevent users from opening a sepcific template (rte) file directly.
My thoughts are to check the file name that is opening if it is the specific template then close it after a dialog notifying the user to user proper procedures creating a project from said template.
I'm working in VB.net (visual basic not c) & Revit 2019 & 2022
Not sure if it's best to embed the code in the document or application.
I've played around with some code in the document but can't get the file to close.

Any ideas/feedback would be helpful.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports Autodesk.Revit.UI
Imports Autodesk.Revit.DB
Imports Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq

<Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Transaction(Autodesk.Re vit.Attributes.TransactionMode.Manual)> _
<Autodesk.Revit.DB.Macros.AddInId("87A056AA-AEB8-4E72-8DCC-D03CA2C8141B")> _
Partial Public Class ThisDocument
Private Sub Module_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
Dim curDoc As Document = Me.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document
Dim DocName As String = curDoc.PathName
Dim CurAdmin As String = Environment.UserName
Dim RevComID As RevitCommandId = RevitCommandId.LookupCommandId("ID_FILE_CLOSE")
Dim uiDoc As UIDocument = Me.Application.ActiveUIDocument
If DocName = "NetworkTemplatePath\_Templates\Revit 2019.rte" Then
TaskDialog.Show("ACCESS ALERT", "DO NOT OPEN THIS TEMPLATE DIRECTLY" & vbCrLf & "Create a Temporary project from the template to access family content" & vbCrLf & _
vbCrLf & "Contact the BIM Manager if you require further assistance" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This template file will now be closed")
End If
‘This is temporary..
‘Future code will be to close the template for designers only, allowing BIM Manager/Coordinator access to editing the template.
Dim CloseDoc As Boolean
CloseDoc = MsgBox("Close Template", vbYesNo)
If CloseDoc Then
uiDoc.SaveAndClose ‘<--- THIS IS NOT WORKING
End If
End Sub
Private Sub Module_Shutdown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shutdown
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question carefully, it appears to me that a better title for it would be `Prevent document opening`, since that is your ultimate goal. Why allow it to be opened at all in the first place? You can easily prevent the opening of a document by subscribing to the [`DocumentOpening` event](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/ca44b05b-3875-ed67-cbff-281d5aef48c6.htm) and cancelling that.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy,
I've been reading through a few of your posts around this topic trying to get my head around C (not as familiar with it)
I'll persevere with it,